# Set fixed size of a QDialog without cutting text

Tags: c++, qt

I currently set a QDialog to have a fixed size using the following code

```
dlg->setWindowModality(Qt::WindowModal); 
dlg->setFixedSize(dlg->size());
```

Now as a result of this code whatever size I save my ui form in QT Designer. It sticks to that size.This however ends up being a issue in some systems and displays. Where my Qlabels begin to cut from the sides due to the shortage of space.I wanted to know what would be the proper way of doing this ? How would I determine which size would accommodate the layout on the form.The form itself has a horizontal layout which has multiple layouts in it ??

Comment: Try calling adjustSize on the dialog, then setFixedSize on its sizeHint instead.

Comment: Could you give an example

Comment: an example of calling those 3 functions? dlg->adjustSize(); dlg->setFixedSize(dlg->sizeHint());?

Comment: I actually wanted that to be an answer so that I could mark it

Comment: Yes it did work for me . Kindly put that as an answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
dlg->adjustSize();
dlg->setFixedSize(dlg->sizeHint());
```